# Paradigm Diagram

Tags: paradigms, diagrams

Does anyone have a diagram showing all significant programming paradigms. Something like this but with paradigms as titles would be ideal:

[image: help page image]

Comment: Not as your example, but programming paradigms do not exactly work that way: http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/paradigmsDIAGRAMeng108.pdf,

Comment: That's a great diagram, thank you. Care to post that as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Resource requests are somewhat marginal off topic here. So we sneak in answers as comments before the admins notice us :)

Comment: okay ;) shall i delete the question?

Comment: Not sure, you have no close votes yet, maybe it's ok.

Comment: This one may be interesting too, not about paradigms but shows how they influenced each other: http://oreilly.com/news/graphics/prog_lang_poster.pdf

Comment: http://griffsgraphs.com/2012/07/01/programming-languages-influences/ 3rd graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As thorsten müller already gave the link to the diagram, and there are no close votes yet, let me take a shot at a proper answer.

First off, the [diagram](http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/paradigmsDIAGRAMeng108.pdf) by Peter von Roy. Note that he is famous for his book [Concepts, Techniques and Models of Computer Programming](http://www.amazon.de/Concepts-Techniques-Models-Computer-Programming/dp/0262220695) (together with Seif Haridi).

While that original book already covers a lot about programming paradigms, Peter von Roy has another book in work, which is title "Programming Paradigms for Dummies". The overview chapter is freely available [at his site](http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pvr/VanRoyChapter.pdf) and is the source of the above diagram - in other words, you will find an excellent 39-page long explanation of the diagram in there.